# Linked list deletion is removing the wrong node

Tags: c, linked-list

Please I need someone help. I'm having trouble with my homework.

This homework is very simple. Create a list(1,2,3) and delete the middle number by creating a function `delnode`. But it must use the function `free()`.

Right now,I have created the list `(1,2,3)` by using linked list method. I want to delete the number 2 but it doesn't work. It should be comes out with `(1,3)` but it comes out with `(2,3)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node{
    int number;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node node;

//prototype function
node* allocateMemory(void);
node* insertNode(node*);
void delnode(node*);

int main(){
    int i,num;
    node* entr = allocateMemory();
    node* p = NULL;

    entr->number = 1;
    entr->next = NULL;

    num = 3;

    for(i=1;i<num;i++){
        if(!p){
            p=insertNode(entr);
        }else{
            p=insertNode(p);
        }

        p->number = i+1;
    }

    while(entr){
        if(entr->number == 2){
            entr->number == NULL;
            break;
        }
        entr=entr->next;
    }

    while(entr){
        printf("%d\n",entr->number);
        entr=entr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

node* insertNode(node* current){
    node* newNode = allocateMemory();
    current->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void delnode(node* current){
    node* temp = allocateMemory();
    temp = current->next->next;
    free(current->next);
    current = temp;
    free(temp);
    return ;
}

node* allocateMemory(void){
    return (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
}
```

Comment: You're trying to implement a linked list.

Comment: Tell us what you actually try to accomplish, then we can try to find the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your guys comments, I have edited it. ^^

Comment: Don't edit your question to fix it, otherwise people that come here with the same problem won't get any help, as your code won't be broken anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this function `delnode` is all kinds of messed up. You don't need to allocate more memory when you're trying to delete a node. You need to ***link the previous to the next, and delete the current***.

```
| prev |      | current |      | next |
|------|      |---------|      |------|
   /\              X               /\
   ||              X               ||
   |================================|
```

It should look more like this.

```
void delnode(node* current)
{
  node* next = current->next;
  // Now we need to find the node previous to this.
  node* prev = entr; // From the start.
  while(prev->next != current) { prev = prev->next; };
  free(current); // delete the current node.
  prev->next = next; // Link the previous node to the next in the list.
}
```

If you're trying to add three nodes, you need to change your loop.

```
node* current = entr;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  int newCount = current->number++; // Increment count.
  current = insertNode(current); // Returns the new node.
  current->number = newCount; // Assign new count.
}
```

If you want to delete the node with `number` of `2`:

```
node* idx = entr;
while(idx)
{
  if(idx->number == 2) { delnode(idx); break; } // Delete node and break.
  idx = idx->next; // Else, go to next node.
}
```

Comment: @amit - Ahh I didn't even notice that! They are still good points so I'll leave it up.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!Yes, it works and thanks for your explaining. It get me understand it easily. ^^

Answer (score 4):

Some issues:

(1) The original list you are creating is [2,3], and not [1,2,3] - your loop iterates for i=1,i=2 - and in each you insert i+1 - resulting in [2,3]

 (2) Your deletion is not doing anything:

```
while(entr){
   if(entr->number == 2){
       entr->number == NULL;
       break;
   }
   entr=entr->next;
}
```

Note that `entr->number == NULL` is only a boolean evaluation and not an assignment - since you use `operator==`

(Note it would fail for `operator=` as well, because you do not want to assign `NULL` to the value - what you really want to do is assign the previous node `next` field.)

P.S.

The terminology for this data structure is a [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), not a "Linear List"